# Is there an easy way to increase the value of a Map object value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I currently have this code, where speciesMap is a map in which the keys have maps as values.

```
var speciesMap = new Map();
...
if(!speciesMap.get(species)) {
    let obj = new Map();
    obj.set('count', 0);
    obj.set('vol', 0);
    speciesMap.set(species, obj);   
}
```

I want to increase the count of a given specie by 1, but the only way I found to do it was like this.

```
speciesMap.get(species).set('count', speciesMap.get(species).get('count') + 1);
```

Is there a cleaner and simpler way to increase the value instead of going down the whole map again to retrieve its value? Same goes for volume, I need to go down the object and add `+ vol` to it.

Wanted something like

```
speciesMap.get(species).set('count', this+1);
```

which obviously doesn't work.

Comment: I guess `obj` should be an object, not a `Map`, when you don't use dynamic keys anywhere?

Comment: I was messing around with this feature since I haven't used dynamic keys in javascript before and got carried away, but yes `obj` can be an object. Would remove a `get()`from the code.

Comment: Yes, you could just do `specialMap.get(species).count++;` :-)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/48897716/1048572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a helper function:

```
function update(map, key, callback) {
    map.set(key, callback(map.get(key)));
}
```

Then your long expression becomes

```
update(speciesMap.get(species), 'count', v => v+1);
```

Comment: I'm still getting used with ES6 fat arrow functions, but this makes sense and it's concise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi's answer is fine, but it's Friday, so...

You can introduce a mutable number class and use instances of that class instead of bare numbers:

```js
class Int {

    constructor(n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    toString() {
        return String(this.n);
    }

    valueOf() {
        return this.n;
    }

    add(m) {
        this.n += m;
        return this;
    }
}


let speciesMap = new Map();
speciesMap.set('elefant', new Map([
    ['count', new Int(0)],
    ['vol', new Int(0)]
]));

speciesMap.get('elefant').get('count').add(1);

alert('count is now ' + speciesMap.get('elefant').get('count'));
```

Comment: Bergi's anwser is somewhat simpler since I really only needed to operate numbers (+1 and +var), but this is a useful tip using classes. +1 for `return this` which is always awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Mutable numbers? Shudder. Lets rather make an immutable map… :D