# js how to implement map[index]++ concisely

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, es6-map

With Array, I can use `array[index]++`

But with Map, I only know `map.set(index,map.get(index)+1)`

I think it looks bad, and if `index` is a long name function, I have to split it into two lines.

Is there a more concise way to implement `map[index]++`

Comment: `Is there a more concise way` no (excluding the obvious - `Map.prototype.incr = function(x) { this.set(x, this.get(x) + 1); }`)

Comment: I think the real question is... Why exactly you need to use a Map object like an array..?

Comment: For example, count each item's num

Answer (score 3):

I could only suggest a helper function, like

```
function update(map, key, fn) {
    return map.set(key, fn(map.get(key), key));
}

update(table, index, i=>i+1);
```

There is no syntactic sugar for assignments, and therefore no shorthand assignments either.

---

If your keys are strings, you could employ a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) with suitable traps to disguise the update as a property access.

```
const mapMethods = {
    has: Function.prototype.call.bind(Map.prototype.has),
    get: Function.prototype.call.bind(Map.prototype.get),
    set: Function.prototype.call.bind(Map.prototype.set),
};
function asObject(map) {
    return new Proxy(map, mapMethods);
}

asObject(table)[index]++;
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Please don't do that. It's scary.</sub>